# Optimizing MongoDB Query Speed in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB query in my Node.js application that I would like to optimize for better performance. The query looks like this:

```
var ReceiveEmailHistoryData1 = await ReceiveEmailHistory.find({
    IsDeleted: false,
    ClientID: ClientID,
    UserID: UserID,
    IsTrash: false,
    $or: [
        { Subject: new RegExp(Search, "i") },
        { FromEmail: new RegExp(Search, "i") },
        { Snippet: new RegExp(Search, "i") }
    ]
});
```

What I Tried:
I've implemented an indexing strategy for the search fields in my database to speed up queries. I've also explored caching mechanisms using Redis to reduce the load on the database server. Additionally, I've looked into query optimization techniques recommended for my specific database system MongoDB . I've reviewed the relevant documentation and blog posts about improving search performance in my technology stack.

What I Expected:
I expected that by creating appropriate indexes, utilizing caching, and optimizing my queries, I could significantly enhance the search speed. I aimed to reduce query response times and provide a more efficient user experience for search operations.

What Actually Resulted:
While I did observe some improvements in search speed after implementing these strategies, the performance gains were not as substantial as I had hoped for. Query response times are still not meeting the desired standards, and I'm looking for further guidance and suggestions to achieve better optimization.

Comment: There is no index I can think of that could speed up arbitrary regexp lookups.

Comment: i have already used the indexing but that is not speed up

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. You're using regexp lookups, there's no way to index them. You'll need to think hard whether you actually need regexps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your query , It seems like you want to implement full text search on `Subject,FromEmail,Snippet` fields . As this string matching is itself a cpu intensive task and your approach with additional condition making it time consuming.

I would suggest Please use atlas-search with custom [analysers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/analyzers/tokenizers/), create custom n-gram indexes which will create tokens of your string,Then using aggregation you will get precise result in less time also it will work in large amount of data